# Importing FORTRAN DLL in C# does not operate on the data inside the DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, import, fortran

I am having an issue when importing a DLL from FORTRAN into C#. Basically the FORTRAN DLL is a database of variables and accessor functions working on the data. I want to use these exported functions to set and get the data from the DLL.

This is what the FORTRAN DLL contains:

```
 ! Database
 include "test.f90"
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: /DBASE/  

 subroutine DBASE_GET_ADDRESS(iAddress, nBytes, Bytes)
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'DBASE_MODULE_mp_DBASE_GET_ADDRESS' :: DBASE_GET_ADDRESS
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: DBASE_GET_ADDRESS

 subroutine DBASE_SET_ADDRESS(iAddress, nBytes, Bytes)
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'DBASE_MODULE_mp_DBASE_SET_ADDRESS' :: DBASE_SET_ADDRESS
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: DBASE_SET_ADDRESS
```

The database is included in "test.f90" and it is exported so other unmanaged code can access it directly. Generally it is aimed to work as shared memory.

The 2 subroutines are accessing the data inside "test.f90". I haven't pasted the whole body as it's a formatting nightmare on SO but they work as intended.

Now my initial thought was that I can import these functions in C# and operate on the database variables (which are also part of the DLL) from there. This is what I have done:

```
    [DllImport("Test_Dbase.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void DBASE_MODULE_mp_DBASE_GET_ADDRESS(ref Int32 iAddress, ref Int16 nBytes, ref Byte Bytes);

    [DllImport("Test_Dbase.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void DBASE_MODULE_mp_DBASE_SET_ADDRESS(ref Int32 iAddress, ref Int16 nBytes, ref Byte Bytes);
```

Then I wrote some wrapper functions so I can pass in a variable name with value for easy access. This seems to work fine with the DLL added in my local solution I can set and retrieve data successfully.

The problem appears when I bring my C# executable in with the other processes
the work on this shared DLL. My executable seems to operate on a local copy of it and no changes are seen in the other processes.

[Top: C# process Bottom: Fortran process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k19Qv.jpg)

I am pretty new to Interop between managed and unmanaged code so it could very well be that my approach is massively flawed. Any input would be appreciated. I can provide more code or info if needed.

Thanks,

Dragos

Comment: Does the DLL immediately flush the changes to disk? Are you sure that the file is opened in sharing mode? I'm not sure you can have multiple writers to a file unless there is some kind of locking mechanism, does that exist?

Comment: regarding your "formatting nightmare on SO", just paste your whole code, highlight it in the editor on SO and press control-K to indent the whole block as code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load dll dynamically.

```
public delegate void FortnarInterface(ref Int32 iAddress, ref Int16 nBytes, ref Byte Bytes);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

IntPtr dllHandle = LoadLibrary("Test_Dbase.dll");
IntPtr functionHandle = Kernel32.GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DBASE_MODULE_mp_DBASE_GET_ADDRESS");

FortnarInterface function =(FortnarInterface)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(functionHandle, typeof(FortnarInterface));

//call your fortran function
function(your arguments here)

Kernel32.FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
```

Comment: It seems to have the same effect as before.